# access json element based select option with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I convert an array php to json like this:

```
var jsoncsv = '<?php echo json_encode($csvData); ?>';
console.log(jsoncsv);
```

The output of those json like this :

```
{"1":
{" NO":"    1",
 "EIR IN":"1545053   ",
 "CONT":"EOLU 1111111",
 "TYPE":"XXXX",
 "INDEPO":"21-11-2015",
 "JAM":"13:00",
 "KODE VSL":"ABO",
 "VESSEL":"ALBERT OLDENDORFF   ",
 "VOY":"N001   ",
 "CONSIG":"ASTABUMI CIPTA      ",
 "COND IN":"DMG",
 "CLEAN":"DIRTY",
 "TARE":"  2400",
 "GROSS":" 20000",
 "KAPASITAS":"  5000",
 "EX CARGO":"FOOD                ",
 "LAST AIR)":"  -  -    ",
 "LAST HIDRO":"  -  -    ",
 "MANU":"10-11  ",
 "BUILDER":"                    ",
 "OWNER":"APL                 "},

"2":
{" NO":"    2",
 "EIR IN":"1545052   ",
 "CONT":"EOLU 1234567",
 "TYPE":"IM04",
 "INDEPO":"21-11-2015",
 "JAM":"10:00",
 "KODE VSL":"202",
 "VESSEL":"WAN HAI 202         ",
 "VOY":"N 001  ",
 "CONSIG":"ANUGERAH AGUNG LUMIN",
 "COND IN":"AVL",
 "CLEAN":"DIRTY",
 "TARE":"  2400",
 "GROSS":" 20000",
 "KAPASITAS":"  1000",
 "EX CARGO":"MAKANAN             ",
 "LAST AIR)":"  -  -    ",
 "LAST HIDRO":"  -  -    ",
 "MANU":"11-13  ",
 "BUILDER":"                    ",
 "OWNER":"APL                 "}}
```

And I have select option ON HTML:

```
<select data-placeholder="Masukkan EIR"  id="search" >
     <?php
        foreach ($csvData as $v) {
             echo '<option value ='. $v['NO'].' >' . $v['EIR IN'] . '- ' . $v['CONT'] . '</option>';
         }
     ?>
</select>
```

With jquery, I manage the select option. The code is looked like this :

```
$(document).on("change", '#search', function(){ 
        var selected = $('#search').val() ;
        /*Passed the selected data, search in json*/
});
```

Assumed, select `option.val` is 2, how can I get all the "2"'s element of the json like `NO`, `EIR IN` ?

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$(document).on("change", '#search', function(){ 
        var selected = $('#search').val();
        var json = <?php echo json_encode($csvData) ?>;
        alert(json[selected]['EIR IN']);
});
```

Your HTML part should be like this:

```
<select data-placeholder="Masukkan EIR"  id="search" >
     <?php
        foreach ($csvData as $v) {
             echo '<option value ='. $v[' NO'].' >' . $v['EIR IN'] . '- ' . $v['CONT'] . '</option>';
         }
     ?>
</select>
```

Notice that you have gap here -> " NO", so there is no "NO" element in your json

Comment: Sorry Mr@Sam, it gives a undefined

Comment: @FadlyDzil I've tested the code, that is because your $v['NO'] has no value, so $('#search').val() is undefined. You should modify your json: " NO" -> "NO" or change $v['NO'] to $v[' NO']. Notice the gap before NO

Comment: Owh, my bad. Thank you so much @Sam